# Scrape content from python string in reverse order using Regex

Tags: python, regex

I got this following content from a html page
`str='http://www.ralphlauren.com/graphics/product_images/pPOLO2-24922076_alternate1_v360x480.jpg\', zoom: \'s7-1251098_alternate1\' }]\n\n\nEnlarge Image\n\n\n\n\n\n\nCotton Canvas Utility Jacket\nStyle Number : 112933196\n\n\n\n$125.00'`

Like so, I have many html pages. I need some way to read the content BEFORE the `style number`. In this case, I need `Cotton Canvas Utility Jacket`. Is there a regex in python to do that? Note that I can start looking for pattern `Enlarge Image` and read whatever comes before I strike `Style number`. The issue is that there are many `Enlarge Image` on the html page. What I have shown above is part of the html page. full html page is [here](http://www.ralphlauren.com/product/index.jsp?productId=112933196&cp=105240616.107042896&ab=tn_boys_cs_jackets&parentPage=family)

In short, I need to find the product name from the linked HTML page. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use a proper parsing tool.

Comment: I'm using Beautiful soup to read the HTML.

Comment: Then add some more code to the question. Right now all this is just guesswork.

Comment: I have code to read the HTML page. That is it. What else is needed?

Comment: Pl see the html content and the page in the link given above. I need the product name from the page.

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup, get `prod-top-content`. Then use Beautiful Soup to extract the data you need within that `<div>`.

Comment: OK. I'll check that. Thanks.